# How to disable PlatfromMenuItem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, menu, widget

How to make a PlatformMenuItem disabled. Seems like there is no "enabled" property to control it.

```
PlatformMenuItem(
  label: 'Undo',
  shortcut:
  const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyZ, meta: true),
  onSelected: () { ...},
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PlatformMenuItem/onSelected.html), if you do not set the **onSelected** or **onSelectedIntent** fields of the **PlatformMenuItem**, it will be disabled. So, you can simply omit these fields when creating the menu item, like this:

```dart
PlatformMenuItem(
  label: 'Undo',
  shortcut:
  const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyZ, meta: true),
  // no onSelected or onSelectedIntent
)
```

Alternatively, you can set these fields to null, like this:

```dart
PlatformMenuItem(
  label: 'Undo',
  shortcut:
  const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyZ, meta: true),
  onSelected: null,
  onSelectedIntent: null,
)
```

Comment: Correct. I changed the "onSelected: () => _canUndo ?_handleMenuSelection() : null" to "onSelected: _canUndo ? () => _handleMenuSelection() : null" and all worked. Thanks.